# how to add elments in Particles.js Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, particles.js

I added `particles.js` in my project `nuxt 3`, I used https://github.com/Joepocalyptic/nuxt-particles,
but when I added any element in `<NuxtParticles>` the element doesnt appear

```
// app.vue
<template>
  <NuxtParticles
    id="tsparticles"
    :options="options"
    @load="onLoad"
    class="h-2/4"
  >
  <p class="text-white z-10">sheikh el moctar </p>
  <Navbar/>
  </NuxtParticles>
</template>
```

what is the solution ?

`Sheikh el moctar` doesnot appear
I tried to control particles using css but I did find any result

Answer (score 0):

you can check this particles package for vue3 from here https://github.com/tsparticles/vue3